# Notify other users to change view C# and ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm coding a simple number game with ASP.NET Core 2.1. I have 2 classes, `Player` and `Room`, where `Room` has `Player1` and `Player2`.

When a player hosts a game, he has to share the room code.

Then, when a player join the room, both player should pick a number in the next view.

After both of them pick a number, the game will start.

What I want to do is when player2 joins the room, notify the player1 page to change to the next view.

And it will be the same when both of them pick the number, it should notify both to start game.

Maybe there is other way to do it, you can advise me.

I have a `GameController` like this:

```
public ActionResult JoinRoom(int playerId, string roomCode)
{
        try
        {
            Player player2 = _playerDA.Get(playerId);
            Room room = _roomDA.Get(roomCode);

            room.Player2 = player2;
            room.Status = 1;

            // Here I should notify Player1 to change to next view. How?
            - - - - - - - - - HERE - - - - - - - -

            _roomDA.Update(room);

            // Here I change player2 to the next view.
            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return new JsonResult(new { Status = 500, Message = "Error" });
        }
}
```

Comment: there is basically two ways to do this. Way 1 SignalR.....I honestly never liked it because it keeps connections open and it requires server side implementation etc.  A lot of people do like SignalR and it is very popular.   I on the other hand like more "vanilla" approaches to programming so I use "polling" which means have JavaScript timer check every so often and update the HTML with the changes found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can recommend is that you consider using SignalR

See here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.1

This is the best way to go as it will give your application the realtime functionality you need.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. I'm reading of what SignalR is about, and i think is the perfect solution. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Let me know if you have any other question